# Searching for upcoming events using foursquare API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, foursquare

I am trying to use the foursquare API to grab upcoming events for one of my local venues:

https://foursquare.com/v/the-yost-theater/4bae7c50f964a52043b83be3

After reading "https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/events" and trying to send a request, I always get a response of zero upcoming events, which is weird because on foursquare's event page for the venue, there are a lot of upcoming events.  I even put the venue ID into their explorer test page but I still get 0 results.  Is it because their upcoming events search is powered by a third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the /venues/events endpoint will only return *current* events at the venue.

The /events/search endpoint is another one to look out for, but only seems to work for specific partners at the moment.